# Determine $g(x)$ such that $(f\circ g)(x) = x^2 - 4x + 5$

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Consider $f(x) = x^2 + 2x + 5$ . Now find $g(x)$ such that $(f\circ g)(x) = x^2 - 4x + 5$ .

Note : I know that it will be easy if we suppose $g(x) = ax+b$ and then solve it but I'm curious about a general method . I mean solving $(g(x))^2 + 2g(x) + 5 = x^2 - 4x + 5$ . And also for all cases , is finding $g(x)$ possible if we have $(f\circ g)(x)$ and $f(x)$ ?

Comment: It's not a matter of "*supposing*" that g(x)= ax+ b.  If g were not linear, then $fog$ would not be quadratic.

Comment: @user247327 I know it is obvious but can you prove it ?

Comment: If $g(x)=ax+b$, then $(ax+b)^2+2(ax+b)+5=x^2-4x+5$ will imply $a^2=1$, $2ab+2a=-4$ and $b^2+2b+5=5$. No such pair of $(a,b)$ exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Assume that $$f (g (x))=h (x) $$

for $x\in A .$

If $f $ is a bijection from $g (A) $ to $h (A) $ then

$$g (x)=f^{-1}(h (x)) $$

In your case,

$$f (x)=x^2+2x+5$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=-1\pm \sqrt{x-4} $$

Comment: Thank you , If the $f$ wasn't bijective then what we can do ?

Comment: You could have many solutions.

Comment: Okay , Thank you a lot .

Answer (score 2):

From  $(g(x))^2 + 2g(x) + 5 = x^2 - 4x + 5$,

\begin{align}
[g(x)+1]^2&=x^2-4x+1\\
g(x)&=-1\pm\sqrt{x^2-4x+1}
\end{align}

For the second question, it depends on $f$. If $f$ is bijective, then $g(x)=f^{-1}(f(g(x)))$.